# updating a data that is bound to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to go about solving. I have a C# app that receives a list of data items from server and they are bound and displayed in a datagrid.  The user must then be able to alter them and add or remove items, then commit these changes back to the server.  the datagrid will basically function as an "edit data" window from pgAdmin 3 or sequel server or whatever, where the user can edit the database table.

I am able to display the items in the datagrid, but not sure how to keep track of all the changes that are made to the list.  When a change is made, the unchanged version of the item must be known as well as the changed version, because the original will need to be deleted and the modified version inserted.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How are you pulling the data from the database?

Comment: @KDiTraglia There is an intermediate server app that gets the data from the db and forwards it to the c# app.  The C# app receives the data through a socket and parses it into a list of data items.  The list is then passed to a window that contains a datagrid.  the window has an ObservableCollection field that is built from this list, and it is used as the itemssource for the datagrid

Comment: Is the intermediate server app going to be what writes the data back to the database?  If so how is it interacting with the database to get the data?

Comment: yes, the server app communicates with the database.

Comment: (It wasn't a yes or no question) ***how*** does the server communicate with the database, ie ADO, Entity, dapper, ODBC connection...etc.  All of these have their own way of helping with these sort of issues.

Comment: Well the server is written in C++ and runs on a linux box.  it communicates with the DB through some library, which isn't really relevant to the matter here.

Comment: Is there no logic on the server to handle updates?  Couldn't you just send the updated list back to the server?  Are you planning on updating the database yourself?  If that's the case which technology are you using to update the database?

Comment: the server allows inserting and removing a data item on the database.  so the c# app would have to send the necessary insert and remove commands to the server in order to update the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a view-model which keeps track of the changes.  Basically each item will have a current value, but also the most recent value from the DB.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //collection of subviewmodel to bind to datagrid
}

public class SubViewModel
{
    //Model instance
    //property to expose db value from model instance
    //field to store old db value
}
public class Model
{
    //db value
    //db information
}
```

Comment: I've heard of this before and have spent days trying to understand it, but it just doesn't make sense to me. I guess I have the model, which would be the data item, but then I don't know what the view model will do.  Will the view-model be bound to the datagrid's itemssource field, and have it contain two models, one for the original data and one for the modified data?

Comment: The view-model basically presents the model information in a way that makes sense from a UI point of view.  Each object on the view-model can wrap a model object or (if you're not too strict on MVVM) it can just be a model object.  In this case it seems like it would be good to have a view-model object wrap each model object (in order to have current and previous values stored).

Comment: So would this involve cloning the original item and storing it in a separate variable in the view-model when the view-model is created?  Then how would I bind the model's fields to the datagrid?  would i just copy all of the properties from the model into the view model?

Comment: That is one way to do it.  Or you could just expose the properties on the model object.

Comment: I'd rather do it that way, but if the viewmodel is the datagrid's itemssource, then wouldn't its properties need to be exposed instead?

Comment: You would have a collection type on your VM that would contain sub-VM objects which would wrap your Model objects.  Each sub-VM object would have a field for the current model object and the old model object.

Comment: ok, so would each model instance be wrapped by a separate vm instance?  And is it possible to bind the models properties directly to the datagrid, or does it have to be the vm properties?

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I don't see how the subViewModel would be needed.  Can't there be just two model instances in the vm? (please see my modification)

Comment: If you have two model instances, how would you associate the two?  Creating a wrapper to hold them both is simply a way of grouping data together for convenience.

Comment: You really shouldn't respond in my answer...  Anyway, the problem with that is that you have nothing to bind to each cell of your datagrid.

Comment: They would be associated because one is the unmodified version and one is the modified version.  So when I commit the changes to the server, I'll iterate through the list of vm's, determining which items to remove and add based on the old and current models.  I guess I could add a boolean field to the view which will be set to true if the current model was modified.  Ok, didn't mean to edit your answer, I just thought it would be easier to communicate my idea that way.  I was thinking of just binding the properties that I added to the vm to the datagrid.

Comment: It sounds like you got it!  Good luck.